# Error al buscar valor en una matriz

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo una búsqueda de una cadena en una matriz, pero me marca error en el IF. El error surge al compilar: "[Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

```
void listado(char pers[100][9], int& lim){

    char busqD[40];
    int k;

    printf("\nCONSULTAS\n\nIngresar el nombre del departamento: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(busqD);

    printf("\n\nID EMPLEADO\tNOMBRE\t\tSALARIO");

    for(int i=0;i<lim;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++){

            k=strcmp(busqD,pers[i][j]);<--ERROR
            if(k==0){
            printf("\n%i\t %s\t %.2",pers[i][0],pers[i][1],pers[i][8]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debes añadir algo más de detalle a la pregunta: ¿Qué error te marca en esa línea? ¿Es a la hora de compilar o en tiempo de ejecución? Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para más información y consejos.

Comment: Quité la etiqueta [tag:c] porque la sintaxis `int& lim` no es código C válido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el algoritmo strcmp que quieres utilizar requiere como argumentos actuales dos punteros a char (dos char *) que son la direccion de memoria de las dos cadenas de caracteres estilo C que quieres comparar.

Eso es porque el segundo argumento que estas enviando, `pers[i][2]` no es una cadena, sino un simple caracter (un char).

Te he hecho un codigo un sencillo para que le eches un vistazo,  escribele "Adrian" o "Pepe" o "Miriam" para que veas como va.

Si tienes alguna duda relacionada mas, estare pendiente por aqui.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
//Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

int main(){
const int MAX = 3;
const char empleados[MAX][50] =
    {
        "Adrian",
        "Miriam",
        "Adrian"
    };

char nombre[50];

cout << "Introduce un nombre";
cin.get(nombre, 50);

for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
    if(strcmp(nombre, empleados[i]) == 0){
        cout << "El empleado " << i
        << " " << " tambien se llama "
        << nombre << endl;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Una cadena de caracteres (he editado la respuesta y he quitado la abreviacion)

Answer (score 0):

Estás comparando el primer carácter de ambas cadenas en esa condición, para realizar una comparación de cadenas deberías recorrerlas caracter a caracter para saber si son iguales, pero para ese procedimiento ya existen soluciones en la biblioteca estándar, por ejemplo "strcmp"

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Compara la cadena apuntada por s1 con la cadena apuntada por s2.
La función retorna un número entero mayor, igual, o menor que cero, apropiadamente según la cadena apuntada por s1 es mayor, igual, o menor que la cadena apuntada por s2.

Un ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
   char s1[5] = "Abeja";
   char s2[5] = "abeja";
   int i;

   printf( "s1=%s\t", s1 );
   printf( "s2=%s\n", s2 );

   i = strcmp( s1, s2 );
   printf( "s1 es " );
   if( i < 0 )  printf( "menor que" );
   else if( i > 0 )  printf( "mayor que" );
   else  printf( "igual a" );
   printf( " s2\n" );

   return 0;
}
```

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <string.h>

void listado(char pers[100][9], int& lim){
char busqD[40];
printf("\nCONSULTAS\n\nIngresar el nombre del departamento: ");
fflush(stdin);
gets(busqD);

printf("\n\nID EMPLEADO\tNOMBRE\t\tSALARIO");
for(int i=0;i<lim;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
        if(strcmp(busqD, pers[i][2]) == 0){//son iguales
            printf("\n%i\t %s\t %.2",pers[i][0],pers[i][1],pers[i][8]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me funciono por un tiempo, pero me marcó después este error: **[Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive] **

Comment: Vale, no tengo el programa completo para confirmartelo, pero en principio estamos comparando un caracter con una cadena, por lo que supongo que usando *busqD, estaríamos pasándole la dirección de memoria donde arranca la cadena, que es lo que está esperando strcmp, prueba y me dices. Un saludo!